# Размеры кнопок в imageset (1x.2x.3x)

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone, icon

Подскажите. Создаю в imageset раздел "backbut", закидываю туда 3 изображения, в mainstaybord выбираю кнопку и в строке background выбираю backbut.

Но вот вопрос: допустим, фон кнопки у меня (ШхВ) 100х50 пикселей, то 2x кнопка у меня должна быть 200х100? А кнопка 3х 300х150?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно так. ) Но, прежде чем задавать такие вопросы, не проще и быстрее ли проверить сначала самому? Это ж пара минут всего!